# Pyscript Trying to fetch data

Tags: pyscript

im trying to fetch data inside this code with pyscript and im not geting any data from db.json do you have solution for me what to do?

i dont see any solution cauase my back json server is fetching data easly and only in when i open liver server nothings happens so i just need to figure it out how to fix it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Students Data</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  <!-- Add axios library -->
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="students-data" style="margin: 20px;">
    <h2>Students Data:</h2>
    <py-placeholder id="students-placeholder">Loading students data...</py-placeholder>
  </div>

  <py-script>
    import js

    def fetchStudentsData() -> dict:
    """Fetches the students data from the server."""
    response = js.axios.get("http://localhost:4000/students")
    if response.status_code == 200:
    return response.data
    else:
    return {}

    def displayStudents(data: dict) -> None:
    """Displays the students data in the HTML."""
    studentsPlaceholder = document.querySelector("#students-placeholder")
    studentsHtml = ""

    if data and "students" in data:
    for student in data["students"]:
    studentInfo = f"ID: {student['id']}<br>Name: {student['name']}<br>Age: {student['age']}<br>Grade:
    {student['grade']}"
    studentsHtml += f"<p>{studentInfo}</p>"
    else:
    studentsHtml = "<p>No data available</p>"

    studentsPlaceholder.outerHTML = studentsHtml

    def onDocumentLoad() -> None:
    """Called when the document loads."""
    console.log("Document loaded.")
    studentsData = fetchStudentsData()
    js.displayStudents(studentsData)

    window.onDocumentLoad = onDocumentLoad
  </py-script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things that are going on here:

The [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) API seems to be promise-based, so they return thenables which need to be awaited or otherwise resolved. In Python, these can be either awaited, or scheduled using a method like `asyncio.ensure_future()`.

You are attempting to iterate over the `data` object (`data["students"]). I can't say exactly what your data looks like locally - I recreated a similar example using the GitHub events API. Note the strategy for iterating over an object with arbitrary keys; if your data is not an Array, you may need to iterate over keys in this way.

Finally, some of your attribute names were incorrect - `status_code` vs `status`, per the axios API:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Students Data</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.js"></script>
  <!-- Add axios library -->
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="students-data" style="margin: 20px;">
    <h2>Students Data:</h2>
    <py-placeholder id="students-placeholder">Loading students data...</py-placeholder>
  </div>

  <script type="py">
        import js
        from js import document, console, Object
        import asyncio

        async def fetchStudentsData() -> dict:
            """Fetches the students data from the server."""
            response = await js.axios.get("https://api.github.com/events")
            if response.status == 200:
                return response.data
            else:
                return {}

        def displayStudents(data: dict) -> None:
            """Displays the students data in the HTML."""
            studentsPlaceholder = document.querySelector("#students-placeholder")
            studentsHtml = ""

            if data:
                studentsHtml = ""
                for item in Object.keys(data):
                    studentsHtml += getattr(data, item).id + "<br>"
            else:
                studentsHtml = "<p>No data available</p>"

            studentsPlaceholder.outerHTML = studentsHtml

        async def run() -> None:
            """Called when the document loads."""
            studentsData = await fetchStudentsData()
            displayStudents(studentsData)

        asyncio.ensure_future(run())
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Which yields for me:
[image: A screenshot of the demo of code, fetching ID's from the GitHub API]